# Ajax with Spring MVC not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my jsp from where I try to inser the user

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add Users using ajax</title>
        <script src="/Spring3MVC/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function doAjaxPost() {
            // get the form values
            var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
            var lastName = $('#lastName').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/insert",
                data: "firstName=" + firstName + "&lastName=" + lastName,
                success: function(response) {
                    // we have the response
                    $('#info').html(response);
                    $('#firstName').val('');
                    $('#lastName').val('');
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add Person</h1>
        <table>
            <tr><td>First Name : </td><td> <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" /><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name : </td><td> <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" /> <br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="info" style="color: green;"></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        <a href="/SpringMVC/search">Show All Users</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insertPerson(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName ) {
    personDao.savePerson(firstName,lastName);
    model.addAttribute("nameAdded", firstName+" "+lastName);
    return "personAdded";
}
```

When I click the 'Add Users' button, nothing happens. Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: what are you expecting it to happen?

Comment: on clicking, I want it to go to the controller code..

Comment: You never call `doAjaxPost()`, do you?

Comment: @sp00m - I am calling it. <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/></td></tr>

Comment: Try using firefox firebug to debug and find what is happening on click. And its always better to use absolute url with contextPath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using contextual URLs everywhere except the Ajax post.

Should

`url: "/insert",`

maybe be

`url: "/SpringMVC/insert",`

or even better

`url: "<spring:url value='/insert' />",`

Comment: Then I suggest you get some good javascript debugging tool (like FireFox with the FireBug plugin) and start debugging your code and network traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Try

`data: {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName},`

instead of

`data: "firstName=" + firstName + "&lastName=" + lastName,`

in your ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `url` in JSP for AJAX request as:

```
url: "insert"
```

in place of:

```
url: "/insert"
```

You are using absolute URL which is pointing to the root of the server and not to your controller.

I have tested it and it's working fine for me with your code.

Answer (score 2):

what is the absolute url for the two pages, and if you hit f12 key on you keybourd you can trace the ajax call and trace the response code, if it's 200 it's ok nothing wrong with your server side code now check the success function otherwise check the server code and ofcourse 404 means it didn't reach the server.